# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: read end tag key with no tags open

Tags: android, android-xml, android-pullparser

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: read end tag key with no tags open (position:END_TAG @1:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@83d457b)

Android 6.0 (API 23)
What's wrong in xml? Or what else could be the reason of that exception?
If i'm not mistaken @1:7 is row 1 and symbol 7 in this row (or may be reverse line 7). But i didn't find what's wrong in this xml.

Thank you very much!

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Golfs</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>GLF_COD</key>
<string>0661</string>
<key>GLF_LIB</key>
<string>AA SAINT OMER GOLF CLUB</string>
<key>GLF_ADR_1</key>
<string>Chemin des Bois</string>
<key>GLF_ADR_2</key>
<string/>
<key>GLF_CPO</key>
<string>62380</string>
<key>GLF_DIS</key>
<string>ACQUIN WESTBECOURT</string>

    public class ClubCategoriesInflater extends XMLInflater<List<ClubCategory>> {

    @Override
    protected void onInflate(List<ClubCategory> clubCategories, InputStream stream) {

        int START_NUMBER = 2;
        int arrayTagNumber = 0;
        ClubCategory clubCategory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = getParser();

        if (parser!=null){
            String startTag = null;
            String lastKey = null;
            try {
                int eventType = parser.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        startTag = parser.getName();
                        if ("array".equals(startTag)){
                            arrayTagNumber++;
                        }
                        if ("dict".equals(startTag)){
                            clubCategory = new ClubCategory();
                        }
                    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                        startTag = null;
                        if (arrayTagNumber==START_NUMBER){
                            if ("dict".equals((parser.getName()))){
                                clubCategories.add(clubCategory);
                            }
                            if ("array".equals((parser.getName()))){
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(arrayTagNumber==START_NUMBER && startTag!=null && eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                        if (key.equals(startTag)){
                            lastKey = parser.getText();
                        }else if (string.equals(startTag)){
                            if ("id".equals(lastKey)){
                                clubCategory.id = Integer.valueOf(parser.getText());
                            }
                            else if ("name".equals(lastKey)){
                                clubCategory.name = parser.getText();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    eventType = parser.next();
                }
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Link to that xml
https://esplic-ws1.ffgolf.org/iphone/get_golfs_plist.php?av=1.2&sv=6.0&sn=Android%20OS&su=c19f0b9cc0a3c911&sl=en&sm=Nexus+7

Comment: Post the actual code. The Java code.

Comment: your <dict> and <array> elements are unclosed

Comment: Robert, <dict> and <array> are closed. Please, that xml
 https://esplic-ws1.ffgolf.org/iphone/get_golfs_plist.php?av=1.2&sv=6.0&sn=Android%20OS&su=c19f0b9cc0a3c911&sl=en&sm=Nexus+7
Thank you